# Does Google API Gateway support web gRPC filtering?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-run, grpc-web, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have Google Run containers serving gRPC services. I'd like to build out a front end using web gRPC on Firebase. I am exploring the usage of Google API Gateway as a proxy between web gRPC and proper gRPC.

I am looking at this guide: https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-run-grpc which doesn't mention web, but I know the gateway is based off Envoy which is used for this purpose quite often. I am wondering if someone has a definitive answer or whether I need to deploy Envoy as a service on Cloud Run by hand to serve as a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, API Gateway supports gRPC-web. API gateway runs ESP-V2, which is built on top of ESP. The original ESP has added the support for grpc-web which is shown in this [GitHub link](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp/pull/283). And it still exists in ESP V2 as we can confirm from this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/pull/176)

API Gateway allows clients to use HTTP/JSON to communicate with gRPC service. You can look at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/grpc-overview#transcoding) and see if it helps your use case.